# Flutter 3.13.9, in iOS Keyboard is stuck on the screen when we switch between different apps

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I have one issue which can only be seen if we perform certain steps. The keyboard is stuck on the screen and even when clicking back from navigation the keyboard still remains.

Steps:

1. Open another app for example notepad and start editing, so that the keyboard appears
2. Click on home
3. Switch to your app.
4. Repeat the above steps

After doing the above steps, the focus is removed from the text field and the keyboard remains on the screen.

[Issue Gif](https://imgur.com/Aq4Lw3u)

[Issue raised in flutter](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/131840). This was closed because I was not able to reproduce it in the latest master channel. But now while upgrading to the latest stable version 3.13.9 I am seeing this.

Any help/lead is appreciated.